# AutoLayout two labels with 30:70 ratio proportional

Tags: ios, storyboard, autolayout

I have two labels green and yellow and i am trying to make them always be in the same proportional to the screen width. I tried aspect ratio and changing the priority etc but not get the final result. I will be very thankful if someone can help me [image]

[image]

Comment: So where are the width constraints? I don't see _any_ width constraints in the screen shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set up constraints for the widths of the views related to the width of the superview.

In your case:

1. Pin the left side of the green view to the view.
2. Pin the right side of the yellow view to the view.
3. Make the horizontal spacing between the green and yellow views to be zero.

Now create a constraint and apply it:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self setupWidthConstraints];
}

- (void)setupWidthConstraints {
    NSLayoutConstraint *widthConstraint;
    widthConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.greenView
                                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                   relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                      toItem:self.view
                                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                  multiplier:0.30
                                                    constant:0.0];

    [self.view addConstraint:widthConstraint];
}
```

This constrains the green view's width to 30% of the view width. And since the yellow view is pinned to the side and the green view, it will take up the remaining 70%.

If you want to see this in action you can get an example project that demonstrates exactly this from https://bitbucket.org/abizern/so27659421/get/master.zip

Comment: @Abizern- Thanks for answer, You have set content hugging priority to 250 for both green and yellow. but it was showing error in mine till i set it to 251 of greenView, even i set the intrinsic size to 100 why it showed in mine ?

Comment: @Abizem- Why is constant to leading space turn up to -16 and where is x is 0.

Comment: That's the layout to the margin. New in ios8